# How to bypass payment page depending on previous page selection

Tags: paypal, billing

Fairly new at all this HTML / CSS stuff, but I'm pleasantly surprised at what I've learned and am certainly not afraid to keep going. My question:

When members join our website they go through three separate pages.  First page they enter basic demographics (name, etc.), 2nd page they choose the desired membership level, and the 3rd page they enter their billing and payment information.

Only **after** the payment gets processed is their account setup and ready for use.

I'd like to make the basic membership FREE for all new users.  So when they arrive at the second page to select their membership, they'll have the option of choosing a package that costs nothing.

Problem is, the last (billing) page is looking for **something** (fyi Paypal is the merchant service, allowing both credit cards and paypal to be the method of payment).  Even if there is a zero balance, this page still requires the user to complete all the fields (address, credit card number, etc.).  And when submitted, the transaction cannot complete because the amount owed was actually $0.00.

So I'm looking for a way that users can bypass this billing page completely if the basic (free) membership is chosen.  I can't figure out how to do it because the system requires payment in order for their profile to become live.

Hope that makes sense.  Any guidance / suggestions would be greatly appreciated, and I'm happy to answer any questions to help clarify.  THANK YOU!  -Joe

Comment: Well, honestly this type of question isn't suitable for SO (too broad). The quick answer is to "skip" the billing page/step as needed. If that's too vague - that's pretty much why this venue probably isn't going to be good. You may need to work with a developer to figure out "your system" and customize it based on your needs...

Comment: Seconded largely because you are not clear what "the system" is. If you are referring to how PayPal works, you should probably  be using a different PayPal product (see Login with PayPal). If you mean some ecommerce/shopping cart product, then the answer lies within that specific product's setup.configuration. Etc.